# Using materialize, wanting to eliminate white space margin on mobile-only

Tags: html, css, materialize

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2qdN.png)I am using materialize framework for building my first basic site, however on mobile only view, the margins are quite wide and i'd like them to take up full screen, so as to make reading better and make the middle card stretch less.

I have also attached a picture now, as you can see the padding and margins are quite wide.

https://codepen.io/jehc10/pen/LKqRRQ

```css
.brand-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  background: #fad1df;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.custom {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid #f1749e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My materialize website</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <main>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper pink lighten-3">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Website</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Cards -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title">Example 1</span>
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Request a quote</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title">Example 2</span>
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Request a quote</a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Middle card -->
    <div class="mobile-margin visible-xs">
      <div class="lg12">
        <div class="card custom light-blue lighten-5">
          <div class="card-content black-text">
            <span class="card-title">Example 1</span>
            <p>
              Mauris accumsan pretium lorem et pretium. In lectus metus, tincidunt a ante nec, porta pretium diam. Integer dolor justo, porta nec scelerisque eget, consequat vel mauris. Curabitur quis ipsum magna. Nullam eu dolor id risus convallis pulvinar sed id
              risus. Aliquam condimentum ullamcorper suscipit. Cras vel ligula sit amet tellus hendrerit tincidunt. Proin nec augue id diam fermentum semper dapibus eleifend diam. Quisque vel urna in ante euismod maximus at sed est. Quisque ut tincidunt
              sapien. Suspendisse ut tempus augue. Cras feugiat elementum lorem, vel pellentesque magna. Mauris accumsan pretium lorem et pretium. In lectus metus, tincidunt a ante nec, porta pretium diam. Integer dolor justo, porta nec scelerisque eget,
              consequat vel mauris. Curabitur quis ipsum magna. Nullam eu dolor id risus convallis pulvinar sed id risus. Aliquam condimentum ullamcorper suscipit. Cras vel ligula sit amet tellus hendrerit tincidunt. Proin nec augue id diam fermentum
              semper dapibus eleifend diam. Quisque vel urna in ante euismod maximus at sed est. Quisque ut tincidunt sapien. Suspendisse ut tempus augue. Cras feugiat elementum lorem, vel pellentesque magna. Mauris accumsan pretium lorem et pretium.
              In lectus metus, tincidunt a ante nec, porta pretium diam. Integer dolor justo, porta nec scelerisque eget, consequat vel mauris. Curabitur quis ipsum magna. Nullam eu dolor id risus convallis pulvinar sed id risus. Aliquam condimentum ullamcorper
              suscipit. Cras vel ligula sit amet tellus hendrerit tincidunt. Proin nec augue id diam fermentum semper dapibus eleifend diam. Quisque vel urna in ante euismod maximus at sed est. Quisque ut tincidunt sapien. Suspendisse ut tempus augue.
              Cras feugiat elementum lorem, vel pellentesque magna. Mauris accumsan pretium lorem et pretium. In lectus metus, tincidunt a ante nec, porta pretium diam. Integer dolor justo, porta nec scelerisque eget, consequat vel mauris. Curabitur quis
              ipsum magna. Nullam eu dolor id risus convallis pulvinar sed id risus. Aliquam condimentum ullamcorper suscipit. Cras vel ligula sit amet tellus hendrerit tincidunt. Proin nec augue id diam fermentum semper dapibus eleifend diam. Quisque
              vel urna in ante euismod maximus at sed est. Quisque ut tincidunt sapien. Suspendisse ut tempus augue. Cras feugiat elementum lorem, vel pellentesque magna.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Table -->

      <table class="responsive-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Alvin</td>
            <td>Eclair</td>
            <td>$0.87</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alan</td>
            <td>Jellybean</td>
            <td>$3.76</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonathan</td>
            <td>Lollipop</td>
            <td>$7.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <!-- Hover button -->

      <div class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
          <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Pagination -->

      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#!">1</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">2</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">3</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">4</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">5</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
      </ul>



  </main>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer class="page-footer pink lighten-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        © 2019 Jesse
        <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: other than mobile-margin being changed, I don't see much difference.  This, however, does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you show the margin using a marker?

Comment: You want something like this - https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/XLGreB?editors=1100, overriding css inside a media query?